# Как вывести json в blade?

Tags: javascript, laravel

Я делаю живой поиск по сайту. Контроллер сделал, js тоже. Мне осталось принять json из контроллера в blade шаблоне, но я не понимаю, как это сделать.

```
public function search(Request $request){
        if($request->search){
            return Post::search($request->search)->get();
        }
    }
```

```
$("#search").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form_data = $(this).serialize(); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: this.action,
        data: form_data,
        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: this.action,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        data: form_data,
        beforeSend: function() {}
    })
    .done(function(json) {
        console.log( 'success:', json );
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log( 'error' );
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log( 'always' );
    });
```

Comment: мне нужно вывести его в blade шаблоне

Comment: Например, `$('body').html( json );`

Comment: мне выдает ошибку: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: открой консоль в браузере и посмотри куда идет запрос и почему там 500

Comment: 500 - ошибка в коде. Можно открыть Инструменты разработчика (CTRL+SHIFT+i) на вкладке Связь (network) можно найти запрос и попробовать посмотреть детали

Comment: Были какие-то проблемы с формой. Сейчас ошибки нет. Как мне выводить не весь массив, а нужные данные по ключу?